# Баг: участник "получил" 2 одинаковых знака

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, знаки

Прилагаю скриншоты. На главной странице, в "недавно полученных знаках" один участник получил 2 знака "Автобиограф", который даётся только 1 раз!
[image: Скриншот]

Но при открытии страницы участника знак только один:

[image: Скриншот 2]

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это два разных участника. Обратите внимание на ссылки профиля:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/474191/tobacco-king
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/474187/tobacco-king

Учётные записи следует объединить. Это работа для модераторов.
Пригляделся получше - это обычные спам-аккаунты с рекламой. Т.е. нужно просто заблочить и удалить.

> [image: Даже больше двух]

Comment: Спасибо. А зачем такой "дубль"?

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 либо эти учётки для накрутки голосов, либо что-то сбойнуло при регистрации и создалось две учётки (сомнительно). В любом случае - их надо объединить.

Comment: Полностью согласен. А как объединить? Модераторы?

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 надо вообще удалить их. По всей сети.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что удалять могут только модераторы?

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 может сам себя удалить, но это маловероятно :)

Comment: Я бы сказал невозможно )))

Comment: Вы перевели их описание?! Это просто реклама. Перевод приложу в своём ответе

Comment: По-моему, это боты - они за день зарегались во всех(!) сообществах StackExchange